# Integration of GUI module with backend code module in python

Tags: python

I am working in python. I have created a GUI in Qtdesigner in a module Gui.Py. I have a code Module which i have created separately. Now there is a problem, i have a method in my code module that prints in while loop for some time. I want my gui textbrowser display that print message in button click event.. How can i do this in real time..
The Sample code is:

Gui..py File

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(400, 211)
    self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(Form)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 256, 192))
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 97, 27))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now Sample.py

```
import time
class A:
def somefunction(self):
    i=0
    while i<100:
        print str(i)
        i+=1
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__=='__main__':
p=A()
p.somefunction()
```

Please help me,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `somefunction` printing the results directly, have it `yield` the results to the caller. The caller can add the strings to the GUI one by one.

However if your results take a long time to generate, as they do with an arbitrary `sleep` function thrown in, you'll block the message loop that most GUIs require to respond to events. In that case you might offload that to a different thread, passing the results back to the GUI thread for display.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the print statement to showup back in your QTextBrowser then you are looking at hooking up some slots and signals.  You can do that in QtDesigner.

If that is the case then you should look at [QTimer](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtimer.html).

```
p = A()
timer = QTimer() #Form as parent??
timer.timeout.connect(p.somefunc)  #different somefunc without the sleep thing
timer.start(2000)    # actually starts on app.exec_()
```